# installing chrome in docker file

Tags: google-chrome, dockerfile

I am trying to install google chrome in docker build with following standard way:

```
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
```

But my proxy does not allow google.com so it fails. Is there other way to install google chrome in ubuntu? I don't want to host any file in network so if there is another source (e.g. github) where I can find debian packages for chrome then I can just get that and run that with dpkg. Or, any other idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a mirror in my network. Replacing source with my mirror, job was done!