# Could not Execute the Chromdriver from the Docker ( /usr/local/bin/chromedriver )

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, azure-functions

I am trying to execute the chrome driver from the docker container but did not succeed with the process, so far I did the following.

1. Implement the Microsoft Azure Functions
2. Implement the Dockerfile
3. Running a docker container successfully

### Python File

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request. 11:38')




    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    path_to_chrome=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')



    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.8

# 0. Install essential packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 1. Install Chrome (root image is debian)
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132615/installing-chrome-in-docker-file
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

# 2. Install Chrome driver used by Selenium
RUN LATEST=$(wget -q -O - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && ln -s $PWD/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"

# 3. Install selenium in Python
RUN pip install -U selenium

# 4. Finally, copy python code to image
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

# 5. Install other packages in requirements.txt
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether chromedriver is in that path or not
To check open CMD and type `chromedriver` (assuming your chromedriver executable is still named like this) and hit enter  if `Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448` is appearing, the PATH is set appropriately

Alternatively you can use a direct path to the chromedriver like this:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

So in your specific case:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Username/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```

Also, you need to install selenium packages

try installing the Alpine compatible version of `chromedriver`, available in Alpine repositories, using `apk add chromium-chromedriver`:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/community/x86_64/chromium-chromedriver