Why my timer trigger function is not triggered when deploying my docker container?
My time trigger function is not triggered when deploying it on Azure functions. I deploy it using docker container because I am using selenium.
This is my function header:
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="0 */5 * * * *", arg_name="mytimer", run_on_startup=False,
              use_monitor=False) 


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
    run()

And these my binding and configure files for more reference:
//function.json
{
    "scriptFile": "function_app.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "mytimer",
        "type": "timerTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
      }
    ]
  }

//host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

This is my function overview, it changed the runtime version but didn't add the function to the Functions list

It run successfully on my local host and is triggered perfectly fine, but when deploying it on azure it doesn't got triggered. I don't get any exception. the real problem that it was triggered even after deploying on Azure and I got exceptions due to some errors with docker, but it was triggered. after deploying it again for multiple of times, it doesn't even got triggered and I didn't change anything in the configurations. for testing it suppose to be triggered every 5 minutes.
This is my Dockerfile for building the image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

# 0. Install essential packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
        unixodbc-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 1. Install Chrome (root image is debian)
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132615/installing-chrome-in-docker-file
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

# 2. Install Chrome driver used by Selenium
RUN LATEST=$(wget -q -O - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && ln -s $PWD/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"

# 3. Install selenium in Python
RUN pip install -U selenium

# 4. Finally, copy python code to image
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

# 5. Install other packages in requirements.txt
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt


Have you added anything in Environment variables > App settings after deployment?
Sometimes it won't be visible if you update any after deployment. Try to deploy it again and check it once.

Are you trying in Python v1 or v2 model?

@DasariKamali No, I didn't add anything in my Environment variables after deployment. I am trying v2 model.

You deployed using Docker container right, Can you share the Docker code here?

No need to use function.json file in Python v2 function model.

I ran successfully in local as well as in Azure Portal and can see the function in the Function app.

@DasariKamali I've edited the question to include my dockerfile. In the beginning I was able to see it yes, even if there is an error with my docker, now I can't even see it and I didn't change anything in the code.

@DasariKamali Actually it is working now, and I didn't even changed anything.  Thank you so much for your help

Well, glad to know this.


it doesn't even got triggered and I didn't change anything in the configurations. for testing it suppose to be triggered every 5 minutes.


Set Up Function App Environment the above function relies on the Azure Functions environment, but there is no proper set up within the Docker container.

Below is the modified Dockerfile considering the adjustments.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10
 
# Install essential packages
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
        unixodbc-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
# Install Chrome
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
&& echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
&& apt-get update -qqy \
&& apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
&& rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
 
# Install Chrome driver used by Selenium
RUN LATEST=$(wget -q -O - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && ln -s $PWD/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
 
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver:${PATH}"
 
# Install selenium in Python
RUN pip install -U selenium
 
# Copy function code into the container
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY . .
 
# Set up Azure Functions environment
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
 
# Start Azure Functions
CMD ["python", "function_app.py"]

After the above modification I am able to connect my image with azure function and running successfully.


I have setup ACR in azure portal and then my deployment is gone through azure container registry while creating the function app.


Function app Setup:

Result :

Console log:
Azure Functions Core Tools  
Core Tools Version: 4.0.3971 Commit hash: f7b0205a869b89a9eb7e823a155ad0b6451a5f1a  
Function Runtime Version: 4.0.1.16815
 
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.000Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006B86525D'.  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.116Z] Generating 1 job function(s)  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.135Z] Found the following functions:  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.137Z] main (TimerTrigger)  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.141Z]  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.143Z] Host initialized (2046ms)  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.148Z] Host started (2103ms)  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.148Z] Job host started  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.151Z] Python timer trigger function executed.  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.151Z] Python timer trigger function ran at 2024-04-30T10:00:00.151483+00:00  
[2024-04-30T10:00:00.151Z] [2024-04-30T10:00:00.151Z] Python timer trigger function executed.



Show the screenshot of functions deployed on Azure Function App 2. Show the logs from Azure Functions > Function > Monitor or Console when the timer trigger is executing

